# Numpy split array by grouping array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, dbscan

There are the following 2 arrays with equal length. My goal is to split the array B into groups defined by the array A. So finally there should be 3 arrays or an list of array. The final list of arrays should consists of the following rows of array B:

- First and second
- Third and fifth
- Fourth

The order is not really relevant.

```
A = array([[-1],
           [ 1],
           [ 0],
           [ 0],
           [ 1]])

B = array([[ 624.5   ,  548.    ],
           [ 912.8201,  564.3444],
           [1564.5   ,  764.    ],
           [1463.4163,  785.9251],
           [1698.0757,  846.6306]])
```

The problem occured to me by using the dbscan clustering function. The A array describes the clusters (0, 1) of the points in array B. The values -1 declares the point as outlier. (The values used are not precise).
My goal is to calculate the compactness, ... of each found cluster

Comment: What's the logic behind your splitting?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: i am its author) was designed with these type of use cases in mind.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
C = npi.group_by(A).split(B)
```

Not sure what you mean by compactness of each group; but rather than splitting and doing subsequent computations, it is typically more efficient to compute reductions over groups directly; whereby you can reuse the grouping object for increased efficiency:

```
groups = npi.group_by(A)
mean = groups.mean(B)
std = groups.std(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep is simple:

```
[data[labels == l] for l in np.unique(labels)]
```

Similarly, you can build a dict in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit lengthy but it should work.

```
final_dict = {}
for counter in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[counter] not in final_dict):
        final_dict[A[counter]] = B[counter]
    else:
        final_dict[A[counter]] = final_dict[A[counter]] + B[counter]

final_array = []
for key,value in final_dict.items():
        final_array.append(value)
```

Basically since you have odd values like `-1` to work with you can set it as keys of a dictionary and then you iterate over the dictionary to get the groups of values which you can then append to a final output array